# Entity Framework relational child data not loading when calling same method from different controller

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have concern with Entity Framework behavior when calling same query from different controller.

For first one data is loaded from FlightController.

[image]

This is other instance when calling same method from TransferController.

[image]

Has anyone faced this issue.

Comment: And the quoteId is the same at the start of each function ?

Comment: Yes, I have checked this by changing in query instead of getting 

`repoG2BQuote.FindById(quoteId)`

I have replace above query with

`IEnumerable<G2BFlight> g2bFlights = repoQuoteFlight.Query().Filter(a => a.G2BQuoteId == quoteId).Get().ToList();`

and now it's return data for both controller but still it's a mystery for me why EF behave like this.

Comment: The only thing i'm thinking about is, maybe the entity have changed between the two functions, but if you call them directly one after another... That's weird